# Export table mysql data with retaining data-types?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has int and string data types in them. I need to export the data and need to retain the data-types. The method I am using to export the data rightnow puts the quotation marks around all of the data

```
SELECT * FROM passwd INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/tutorials.txt'
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I want the double quotes to be around the varchar?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

If you specify OPTIONALLY, the ENCLOSED BY character is used only to enclose values from columns that have a string data type (such as CHAR, BINARY, TEXT, or ENUM)

Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: How does this fix it ?

Comment: @RohitGupta See [LOAD DATA INFILE ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). _If you specify OPTIONALLY, the ENCLOSED BY character is used only to enclose values from columns that have a string data type (such as CHAR, BINARY, TEXT, or ENUM):_

Comment: you missed the point.  You needed to make your answer more complete and better quality, otherwise it risked getting deleted.  I have shifted your comments to your post.  And I have up voted it :-)